# asynchronous call to stored procedure in MVC Controller example

Tags: asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures, asynchronous, controller

I have never used  asynchronous calls, could some one please provide me a sample how to call a SQL stored procedure from MVC controller ?

```
public ActionResult ReProcess(string uname)
{

SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand();

cmd.Connection = cnn;

cnn.Open();

cmd.CommandText = "dbo.userdetails_sp";

cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;

cmd.Parameters.Add("@userId", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = uname; ;

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();



}
```

Comment: Your question is a little vague. What's wrong with the code you've tried? What are you expecting to see vs. what is actually happening?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Task class to encapsulate a method and then run it asyncronously:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx

```
var t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoAction());
```